# ObjectIDGenerator implementation

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, xna, cross-platform

I was attempting to use ObjectIDGenerator in C# to generate a unique ID during serialization, however, this class is not available in the XBox360 or Windows Phone 7 .NET frameworks (they use a compact version of .NET). I implemented a version using a dictionary of Object to Int64 and was able to get a fully working version up, however, the performance is unsatisfactory. I'm serializing on the order of tens of thousands of objects, and currently this is the greatest bottleneck in save/load performance. Using the actual .NET implementation on PC it takes about 0.3 seconds to serialize about 20,000 objects. Using my implementation, it takes about 6 seconds.

In profiling, I found that the heavy hitters were .TryGetValue and .Add on the dictionary (which makes sense since it's both indexing and adding to the hash map). More importantly, the virtual equality operator was being called instead of simply comparing references, so I implemented an IEqualityComparer that only used ReferenceEquals (this resulted in a speed increase).

Does anyone have an insight into a better implementation of ObjectIDGenerator? Thanks for your help!

My Implementation: http://pastebin.com/H1skZwNK

[Edit]
Another note, the results of profiling says that the object comparison / ReferenceEquals is still the bottleneck, with a hit count of 43,000,000. I'm wondering if there's a way to store data along side this object without having to look it up in a hash map...

Comment: It might help if you can post some sample code which adds the 20,000 objects and reports timings in a console app so others can quickly toy around with your code and post results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it possible to use an `Int32` Id property / handle for each object rather than `Object`? That may help things. It looks like you're assigning an Id type number to each object anyway, only you're then looking up based on the Object reference instead of the Id. Can you persist the object id (your `Int64`) within each object and make your dictionary into `Dictionary<Int64, Object>` instead?

You might also want to see if `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` or `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` perform better or worse. But if your main bottleneck is in your `IEqualityComparer`, these might not help very much.

**UPDATE**

After looking at the `ObjectIDGenerator` class API, I can see why you can't do what I advised at first; you're creating the ids!

`ObjectIDGenerator` seems to be manually implementing its own hash table (it allocates an `object[]` and a parallel `long[]` and resizes them as objects are added). It also uses [`RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11tbk3h9.aspx) to calculate its hash rather than an `IEqualityComparer` which may be a big boost to your perf as its always calling `Object.GetHashCode()` and not doing the virtual call on the derived type (or the interface call in your case with `IEqualityComparer`).

You can see the source for yourself via the [Microsoft Shared Source Initiative](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx):

Comment: ligos, thanks a million for the response, I didn't even know the source was available! I'm going to go take a look and see if I can't do something similar.

Comment: You should be able to look behind the scenes for the `Dictionary<T, K>` implementation too; to get some idea why its taking longer. The shared source is a well kept secret more .NET developers should be aware of!

Comment: Amazing! I found the implementation and it worked right out of the box (I just had to remove some debug / contract stuff that wasn't available on XBox builds). Really, thank you! This wouldn't be the first time that I've had missing implementations of classes on XBox, and now I can go right to the source!

Comment: I'd be a little bit careful about copying the source verbatim. There may be licensing / royalty issues. Especially if you're going to make a profit from your XNA game. Read the license on Microsoft's source carefully!