# Is it possible to get equivalent of 'memory address' of .net Object?

Tags: .net, memory-address, object-identity

We are rolling a custom serialisation tool into our project and are coming across a need to uniquely identify each object by a primitive value type that can be used as a synonym of its 'identity'. The value need have no meaning or organisation, merely that it is unique and persistent at least for the duration of a serialisation routine. Ideally .net would have internally maintained a unique and persistent object ID that we could store as the object's ID. I know every object has a `GetHashCode` method, but we are not confident in the value's global uniqueness. Another criteria on accessing such an ID is that the method needs to be very efficient.

I have looked at `GetHashCode`, the garbage collector and marshalling for ideas, haven't come to anything solid yet.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the [`ObjectIDGenerator` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx), which does exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Is this based on an Object>Integer dictionary?

Comment: Actually it appears to be based on a Hashtable, does this imply the object's `GetHashCode` method is fundamentally responsible for ID uniqueness?

Comment: Further research, as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789430/objectidgenerator-implementation the `ObjectIDGenerator` uses the `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(Object)` method, which by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx is using a `HashTable` and then by http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.objectidgenerator.aspx uses the `Object.GetHashCode` method which itself by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458139/net-is-type-gethashcode-guaranteed-to-be-unique is not necessarily unique.